# Stalled HTTP request (chrome) using own web server

Tags: c#, sockets, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I'm writing an embedded HTTP server for educational purposes in C# (getting more into the rfc and learning something about winsock).

For now I can serve static web pages. The server itself seems to be reasonable fast with one great exception. Chrome loads my test page very slowly in comparison to the IE. In addition the captured network log reveals a big latency for each request.

The web server and browser are running on the same machine, so network latency should be minimized.

I looked at other .NET HTTP server implementations. Implementations using the HttpListener are not showing this behaviour. Socket implementations I found are as slow as my implementation.
At the moment I try to figure out why Chrome behaves so different from other browsers and why the HttpListener does not suffer from this (I know the HttpListener uses the HTTP API 2.0 but I don't know if this API itself uses winsock or something else).

I will attach the important code to accept, read and respond to a single request, as well as the network logs of IE and Chrome.

My current code to accept new sockets is:

```cs
        socket.Listen(10);

        IAsyncResult asyncResult = null;
        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            if (asyncResult == null)
                asyncResult = socket.BeginAccept(null, null);

            if (asyncResult.IsCompleted)
            {
                var acceptedSocket = socket.EndAccept(asyncResult);
                var connection = new HttpServerConnection(acceptedSocket);
                var queue = this.queue;
                queue.Enqueue(connection);
                asyncResult = null;
            }
            else
            {
                Thread.Sleep(5);
            }
        }
```

The queue of accepted sockets is worked by another background thread. The listener waits until data is readable from the socket using `socket.Poll(1000, SelectMode.SelectRead);` (because Chrome opens multiple connections to the HTTP server to theoretically speed up page loading).

After handling the request by the server, a response is send using:

```cs
         var response = context.Response;
        var connection = context.Connection;

        byte[] buffer;
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(1024))
        {
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.ASCII, 1024, true))
            {
                writer.Write(HttpVersion.Http11.ToString());
                writer.Write(" ");
                writer.Write((int)response.Status);
                writer.Write(" ");
                writer.WriteLine(response.StatusDescription ?? response.Status.ToString());

                foreach (var httpHeader in response.Headers)
                {
                    writer.Write(httpHeader.Key);
                    writer.Write(": ");
                    writer.WriteLine(httpHeader.Value());
                }

                if (response.Content != null)
                    writer.WriteLine();
            }

            if (response.Content != null)
                response.Content(context, stream);

            stream.Position = 0;

            buffer = new byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }

        connection.Send(buffer);
```

The first page load by IE, including captured netword and server logging:
[image: IE network log]

[image: server log]
As you can see, except the first request (because request parser and pipeline are initialized the first time being used), are handled fast enough. Responses are received by the IE within 16ms.

Now the first page load by Chrome:
[image: Chrome network log]

[image: Server log]

The server handled responses as fast as they come from the IE, but Chrome takes ~300ms for each request.

Edit: Request/Response for HTML page (first HTTP request)
[image: Request/Response for index.html]

Any clue why there is this behaviour and possibilities to resolve it are greatly appreciated!

After some more researching I found the reason for this behaviour. Somehow Chrome needs way longer to resolve the host name from the host file for the loopback adapter. Using the IP address instead of "localhost" results in acceptable response within 10ms.
The reason this behaviour does not occur if using HttpListener is the simple fact that the HttpListener creates UrlGroups using the HTTP API to map URI with the underlaying socket.

Comment: are you setting any length header?

Comment: The content-length response header is there. I set it to 0. In this case Chrome correctly ignores the complete message body but the latency remains the same. I added the request/response for the first HTTP request. Do I miss required response headers?

Comment: A packet capture (at cloudshark.org) could help to better compare the behavior of the browsers because you could see the timing of all packets from request and response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more researching I found the reason for this behaviour. Somehow Chrome needs way longer to resolve the host name from the host file for the loopback adapter. Using the IP address instead of "localhost" results in acceptable response within 10ms.
The reason this behaviour does not occur if using HttpListener is the simple fact that the HttpListener creates UrlGroups using the HTTP API to map URI with the underlaying socket.